Rails + Ranscaker, How to hide empty params in url
I have created search forms using Ransack, but I have a problem. When I leave input empty I would like form not to send these inputs, so it won't appear in my parameters.
Right now when i leave filters empty

They anyway apear in my url params

I am affraid that when I add many more filters it would cause problems
How could I get rid of that? I understand that I am passing '' in that input.
controller:
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Record.ransack(params[:q])
    @records = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end

form:
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


params[:q].compact_blank. But you're worrying needlessly and it might actually introduce edge cases.

I have already tried it, but it does not change anything. The problem is not that I pass empty params to Record.ransack(...), problem is that it empty params are shown in browser path ://

As I already said leave it be. The browser will serialize inputs as it sees fit and there is no actual benefits to your workaround.

You are worried about the length of the URL in the event nothing is submitted but think about if values are submitted. Maximum URL length to be cross browser compatible is ~2,000 characters, this is a browser based specification not an HTTP spec. If there is a real fear you will exceed this then you should change the request to be POST rather than GET. That being said before you go through any of this I would seriously consider what the actual real world potential is.

I have managed to achieve my goal by using jQuery:
$(document).on('submit','form#form_id',function(){
  $(this)
    .find('input,select')
    .filter(function () {
      return !this.value;
    })
    .prop('name', '');
});

